# Indentation issue of an itemize/enumerate environment in a description environment

Tags: enumerate, itemize, description

I have an itemize environment in a description environment that gives more indentation for the first item.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    \section{Acronym rules}
    \begin{description}
        \item [KISS] Keep it simple and stupid.
        \item [SIPI]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Simple over Easy
            \item Idea over Facts
            \item Process over Product
            \item Internalization over Experience
        \end{itemize}
    \end{description}

\begin{description}
  \item [Feynman's problem solving technique]
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Write down the problem.
    \item Solve the problem.
    \item Write down the answer. 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with `enumitem`. For the second description, it seems fine to me, unless you want to begin `itemize` on the next  line.:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \section{Acronym rules}
    \begin{description}
        \item [KISS] Keep it simple and stupid.
        \item [SIPI]
        \begin{itemize}[wide=0.6em, before=\leavevmode\vspace{\dimexpr-2\topsep-\baselineskip\relax} ]
            \item Simple over Easy
            \item Idea over Facts
            \item Process over Product
            \item Internalization over Experience
        \end{itemize}
    \end{description}

\begin{description}
  \item [Feynman's problem solving technique]
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Write down the problem.
    \item Solve the problem.
    \item Write down the answer.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]